Compare Columns in DF & drop rows if Dates are matching between Columns
I have df as below. If Column Buy Exit Date is having Date (YYYY/MM/DD) matching with Column Buy Date having Date (YYYY/MM/DD) in next row, then drop the Buy Date row from its matching condition.
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Buy Date': ['2022/11/07 15:00:00', '2022/11/11 12:00:00', '2022/11/24 15:00:00', '2022/12/01 12:00:00', '2022/12/14 09:00:00'],
    'Buy Exit Date': ['2022/11/11 09:00:00', '2022/11/24 12:00:00', '2022/12/01 09:00:00', '2022/12/06 09:00:00', '2022/12/16 09:00:00'],
    'ln_entry': [3232.899902, 3315.000000, 3381.699951, 3476.149902, 3364.699951]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df:
      Buy Date          Buy Exit Date       ln_entry
0   2022/11/07 15:00:00 2022/11/11 09:00:00 3232.899902
1   2022/11/11 12:00:00 2022/11/24 12:00:00 3315.000000
2   2022/11/24 15:00:00 2022/12/01 09:00:00 3381.699951
3   2022/12/01 12:00:00 2022/12/06 09:00:00 3476.149902
4   2022/12/14 09:00:00 2022/12/16 09:00:00 3364.699951

Expected Output:
    Buy Date            Buy Exit Date       ln_entry
0   2022/11/07 15:00:00 2022/11/11 09:00:00 3232.899902
1   2022/12/14 09:00:00 2022/12/16 09:00:00 3364.699951

My Code:
df['Buy Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Buy Date'])
df['Buy Exit Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Buy Exit Date'])
df['Buy Date Only'] = df['Buy Date'].dt.date
df['Buy Exit Date Only'] = df['Buy Exit Date'].dt.date
df['Next_Buy_Date_Only'] = df['Buy Date Only'].shift(-1)
to_remove = df['Buy Exit Date Only'] == df['Next_Buy_Date_Only']
df_cleaned = df[~to_remove]
df_cleaned = df_cleaned.drop(columns=['Buy Date Only', 'Buy Exit Date Only', 'Next_Buy_Date_Only'])
print(df_cleaned)

My Output:
  Buy Date            Buy Exit Date        ln_entry
3 2022-12-01 12:00:00 2022-12-06 09:00:00  3476.149902
4 2022-12-14 09:00:00 2022-12-16 09:00:00  3364.699951


I'm happy you got a solution, but Stack Overflow is a Q&A site and there's no question here. We're not here to do your debugging for you, if that's what you thought. Check out [ask] for tips.

The problem seems to have been a basic logic error (you wanted to shift Buy Exit Date forward but instead you shifted Buy Date back), which is not considered a useful question on SO. In the future, check out [mre]; restarting from scratch might help you catch mistakes like this yourself :) See also good reproducible pandas examples

With your current code you are shifting 'Buy Date' one row back, then checking for equality with 'Buy Exit Date' and keeping rows where condition is False. I.e.:
df[['Buy Exit Date Only', 'Next_Buy_Date_Only']]

  Buy Exit Date Only Next_Buy_Date_Only
0         2022-11-11         2022-11-11 # equal: delete (via `~`)
1         2022-11-24         2022-11-24 # equal: delete
2         2022-12-01         2022-12-01 # equal: delete
3         2022-12-06         2022-12-14 # unequal: keep
4         2022-12-16               None # unequal: keep

But this is not the requirement. You want to delete rows where the  'Buy Exit Date' from the previous row equals 'Buy Date'. Try:
df['Buy Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Buy Date'])
df['Buy Exit Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Buy Exit Date'])
out = df[df['Buy Date'].dt.date != df['Buy Exit Date'].dt.date.shift(1)]

out

Output:
             Buy Date       Buy Exit Date     ln_entry
0 2022-11-07 15:00:00 2022-11-11 09:00:00  3232.899902
4 2022-12-14 09:00:00 2022-12-16 09:00:00  3364.699951

The comparison being:
     Buy Date Buy Exit Date
0  2022-11-07          None # unequal: keep
1  2022-11-11    2022-11-11 # equal: delete
2  2022-11-24    2022-11-24 # equal: delete
3  2022-12-01    2022-12-01 # equal: delete
4  2022-12-14    2022-12-06 # unequal: keep

